# Trick in solving for $x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I solve for $x$ given this equation? I tried letting $y=\ln x$ but that does not help.

$$\ln(x)+x\ln2=0$$

Comment: There is no 'closed form' solution (in the usual sense). There is a root around 0.64118574450498...

Answer (score 3):

This is equivalent to : $x>0$ and $x2^x=1$ , in other words: $x>0$ and $\ln(2)xe^{\ln(2)x}=\ln(2)$ and using [Lambert function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_1)
we have $W(\ln(2))=x\ln(2)$ or $x=\frac{W(2)}{\ln(2)}$

Comment: It's Lambert function, not d'Alembert function.

Comment: $\ln(x)+x\ln2=0$ and $x2^x=1$ are not equivalent since the first equation makes no sense if $x \leq 0$, while the second is defined for all _x_.

Comment: @BernardMassé Agreed, but neither equation is true if $x \leq 0$, so the two equations will have the same solutions.

Answer (score 2):

$$\ln(x) + x\ln2 = \ln(x) + \ln(2^x) = \ln(x2^x)$$
Now $$\ln(x2^x) = 0$$
implies
$$x2^x = 1$$.
That's about as close as you can get.